# Android programming send continuous data from class to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bluetooth

I'm working on a project where i have to create a mobile app that reads out a sensor through Bluetooth. I have already coded the Bluetooth connection and i can successfully connect to my sensor and print out the received data. As soon as i am connected it keeps listening to the inputstream as shown in the code below.

My problem is that I don't know how to properly send this data to my fragment. Normally I would use intents to send data but since I receive data continuously I cannot use this method. I've been struggling to find a solution for this for a few days now so any solutions or suggestions are much appreciated.

Current project structure:

**MainActivity.class**, Creates instance of SensorConnector.class.

**SensorConnector.class**, Creates a thread that reads out the sensor. like so :

```
        public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;
        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes); 

                // Code to send incomingMessage to Dataview

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "disconnected " + e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**DataviewFragment.class**, The fragment where i would like send my sensordata. Contains a textbox that i would like to continuously update with the read sensor data.

**DataviewActivity.class**, Implements the Dataview fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to do this, however I'd use simple interfaces and Observer pattern to do the job.

1) Define an interface :

```
public interface SensorListener {
    void onUpdate(String incomingMessage);
}
```

2) Make your `MainActivity` and `DataView` Fragment implement the interface:

Fragment:

```
public class DataView extends Fragment implements SensorListener {
    // or however its setup
    @Override public void onUpdate(String incomingMessage) {
        // Do whatever you need - use runOnUiThread if touching views
    }
}
```

Activity: (note `FragmentManager` maybe support version, `findFragmentByTag` maybe `findFragmentById`, again don't know your setup)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorListener {
// or whatever your current setup is

    @Override public void onUpdate(String incomingMessage) {
        final DataView fragment = (DataView) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("DataView");
        if(fragment != null){
            fragment.onUpdate(incomingMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

3) Update your Sensor class:

```
public class SensorConnector {


    private SensorListener listener;

    public void setSensorListener(SensorListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void removeListener(){
        this.listener = null;
    }

    public void startThread(){

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytes;
                    // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            // Read from the InputStream
                            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                            String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);

                            // Code to send incomingMessage to Dataview
                            if(listener != null) {
                                listener.onUpdate(incomingMessage);
                            }

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "disconnected " + e);
                            break;
                        } finally {
                            removeListener();
                        }
                    }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

4) In your `Activity` set the listener: `sensorConnector.setListener(this);`

I have chosen to go through the MainActivity first before going directly to the Fragment as you might want multiple `Fragment`s to observe the update from the `Activity` - this is easily adaptable to do this, or indeed anything that implements the interface.  Also `removeListener()` is not exclusive to the `SensorConnector` this should be removed when the `Activity` is destroyed, to remove any reference (don't know the scope/lifecycle of your `SensorConnector` class).

Answer (score 2):

You could try a Listener pattern.  Your fragment would implement a listener interface, and your connector would implement a notifier interface.  Register your fragment with the notifier and when your connector receives data, notify your listener(s).  The main thing to remember is that your listener, when called by the notifier, must do it's update work on the same thread as the fragment.  You can do that with a `Handler` object on your fragments thread.

For example you might have the fragment implement the following interface:

```
interface ListenerInterface {
    void update(Object data);
}

public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements ListenerInterface {
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void update(final Object data) {
        //handle the notification here, use a Handler to do the work on
        // the ui thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // this runs on the fragment's ui thread
            }
        });
    }
    // ...
}
```

On your connector a notifier interface might look like this...

```
interface NotifyInterface {
    void registerListener(ListenerInterface listener) {
}

public class MyConnector implements NotifyInterface {
    ListenerInterface mListener = null;

    @Override
    public void registerListener(ListenerInterface listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    private void doUpdate(Object data) {
        if(mListener != null) {
            mListener.update(data);
        }
    }
    // then in your data generation code, call doUpdate as needed
}
```

With this approach you get the added benefit of keeping your UI login in the UI and your data logic in the connector.